# What is an equivalent to Global.getControllerInstance in Play 2.4?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.4

I am migrating a (Scala) Play 2.3 app to 2.4. Previously I had a home-spun mechanism for building my `Controller` objects, and provided them to Play using `Global.getControllerInstance`. This is no longer available in 2.4. Is there a simple way to achieve the same effect? I'd rather not switch immediately to using Guice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a Guice Module facade to wrap your custom controller generator.  You just need to write a single Guice class that will be used by Play to inject your custom generated instances, without any other changes.

Here is an example in Java.  (Sorry, I do not have a scala example handy).

```
package com.example;
class ControllerProviderModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Provides
    MyController1 providesMyController1() {
        // Create MyController1 and return it.
    }

    @Provides
    MyController2 providesMyController2() {
        // Create MyController2 and return it.
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // Alternatively, use other approaches to bind controller classes to your custom generated instances 
    }
}
```

Add your module to Play.

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.example.ControllerProviderModule"
```